# USB3.0 VisionカメラのAndroid接続方法について

Tags: android, camera, usb

USB3.0 Visionカメラを購入してスマートフォン上で映像表示をさせたいと思っています。

UVCカメラとスマホの接続記事はよく見るのですが、Visionカメラとスマホを接続する記事は見られませんでした。
Visionカメラのスマホ接続は難しいのでしょうか。

Comment: ほとんどすべてのスマホは USB 3.0 SS 非対応なので USB 3.0 Vision カメラの性能をフルに発揮させることはできないっス。だから記事も少ないのだと思います。接続すること自体は問題ないはず。でも役に立つかどうかは話が別。

Comment: 相応しいか分かりませんがこんな記事があるようです。[Android端末 USB 3.0 カメラ接続 | インフィニテグラ](https://infinitegra.co.jp/blog/androidusb30cameraconnection/), [車輪の再発見みたいな？ - Android - Camera](https://serenegiant.com/blog/?cat=11), [Android用pylonによるBasler USB3 Vision対応カメラの運用方法](https://www.baslerweb.com/jp/sales-support/downloads/document-downloads/getting-started-with-basler-pylon-and-usb3-vision-cameras-on-android/), [USB3 Visionその実力とは・・・ - 東芝テリー](https://www.toshiba-teli.co.jp/pdf/technology/seminar/s0002_ITE2015_j.pdf), [新しいマシンビジョン標準規格 USB3Visionの概要 - 日本 ...](http://jiia.org/wp-content/themes/jiia/pdf/report2013_02.pdf)